# 3 ring jack no longer working

Tags: windows-10-mobile, headset

I have a 3 ring headphone jack (that contains a microphone) and it used to work fine with 8.1 but after upgrading to 10 it's not being detected anymore.

This can't be a hardware issue since the jack works on different phones and normal 2 ring jacks also work.

I tried shutting down and soft restarting the phone, reinstalling Gadgets but no luck.

Does anyone have anymore ideas?

Comment: Have you tried removing and re-adding the device in the gadgets app?

Comment: @KolappanNathan yes, does not work

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing more I could think of other than Hard reset.

Have you performed any hard resets after upgrading from 8.1?

As I have seen many users have faced problems after the upgrade which are solved by a Hard reset. Even websites like Windows central, MS power user advised a hard reset after upgrading to W10M for better experience. Note that hard reset will erase all of your data in phone memory.